# Stripe Subscriptions - not trying backup / non default cards

Tags: stripe-payments

I have Stripe Subscriptions set up, on their Billing > Scale plan, which includes the Smart Retries feature.

But I have noticed that it does **not**:

- try any backup cards if the default card fails
- will only try processing payment against the customer's **default** card, so if the customer doesn't have a card set to default (but still has a card stored), it will not attempt payment. I have a number of customers woth cards stored that are just not tagged as default.

It seems silly that Stripe's "Smart Subscriptions" will not try anything other than a card set to 'default', the whole point of backup cards is to try them when another fails.

Before I dive into building a custom solution to retry failed subscriptions against backup cards, I just wanted to check if anyone does know of a way to make Stripe automatically try non-default cards, or if I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've since chatted with Stripe customer support, who have confirmed it's not possible:

> Due to security measures, the retried will attempt to pay the default payment method selected either by your customers election using the customer's portal, the merchant account settings, or the lasters payment (Becoming the default payment method in some cases). Other cards will not be used.

> The cards saved are saved by the merchant election, if you want another card to be used you can update your customer's default payment method. Bear in mind we do not offer any option for customers to have a backup card, we only offer the option for the merchant to save payment methods for future usage.

Oh well.